# Postman tests: Как проверить на наличие конкретного значения у ключа, для каждого объекта в массиве?

Tags: javascript, json, get, test-automation, postman

В JSON - объекты которые находятся в массиве, задача: проверить что ключ (который есть во всех объектах) имеет конкретное значение ('orange').

JSON:

```
"ud": {
    "types": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "class": "orange"

        },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "class": "orange"

        }
     ]

 }
```

Реализация для одного объекта в массиве:

```
pm.test("Значение orange у ключа  class в первом объекте массива", function() {
    const dataJson = pm.response.json().ud.types.[0].class;
    pm.expect(dataJson).to.eql('orange');
});
```

Аналогичным образом можно сделать для остальных объектов, но это будет не правильно так как в будущем возможна ситуация когда объектов в массиве будет меньше или больше - соответственно тест упадет.

Comment: У массива есть метод `every` - https://doka.guide/js/array-every/ используй его для теста. ;)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить через валидацию по Json Schema.
Помимо проверки наличия конкретного значения у ключа, будет проверяться вся структура json'a и типы всех ключей.

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json();
var schema = {
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "ud"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "ud": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "types"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "types": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": [
                            "id",
                            "class"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "class": {
                                "type": {
                                    "const": "orange"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var result = tv4.validateMultiple(jsonData, schema);
if (result.valid) {
    pm.test('JSON is valid', function () {
        pm.expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
    });
}
else {
    pm.test('JSON is invalid', function () {
        pm.expect(result.valid).to.be.true;
    });
    console.error('JSON is invalid');
    console.log(`In JSON on '${result.errors[0].dataPath.slice(1)}' ${result.errors[0].message}`);
    console.log(`In JsonSchema on '${result.errors[0].schemaPath}' may be error`);
};
```